# ORM regular expression

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

How to use regular expressions in Django ORM? I've found `__search` and `__contains` field's postfix, but `__regexp` dosn't works.

---

The solution is to use `__regex` instead of `__regexp` if someone stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What do you mean it doesn't work? What regular expression did you try and what happened? It should work just as it says in the docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#regex

by simply putting your regex string in the query.

Comment: "by simply putting your regex string in the query." <-- tried this, online reg expression tool shows it's ok, queryset doesn't find anything. plain simple dummy email regexp `r'\w+@\w+\.\w+'` http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ works in here