# How to use filter to check if strings stored in a Django array field are a substring of the input string

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

Here is how my model looks like.

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
   test_field= ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True),default=list)
```

I want to filter objects which have any substring of the input string as an entry in their test_field.

**Example:**
Assume a TestModel instance object1 has the ['good','morning'] stored in its test_field. object2 has ['run','crew'].
Input String is 'Good Evening'.
The output should return a query set containing object1.

Comment: maybe an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9140958/16250404) for similar question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **overlap** lookup:

```
TestModel.objects.filter(test_field__overlap=["Good", "morning"])
```

Comment: This will check whether any of the words in `["Good", "morning"]` are part of the array field right? Thats not what I want. I want to check if there is a string like "GoodMorning" then if any of its substrings are stored in the array field